# Overwrite Environment Variable Params with export BEHAT_PARAMS

Tags: php, behat

I am trying to use [environment-variable-behat-params](http://behat.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration.html#environment-variable-behat-params) to overwrite the following value in my `YAML`:

```
my_profile:
   suites:
      domain:
         contexts:
            - MyContext:
               - my_config:
                  setting_setting: data
                  other_setting_setting: other_data
```

This is the export command:

```
export BEHAT_PARAMS='{"suites":{"domain":{"contexts":{"MyContext":{"my_config":{"my_setting":"on"}}}}}}'
```

And this is the PHP code:

```
/** @BeforeSuite */
public static function prepare(BeforeSuiteScope $scope) {
    $my_settings = $scope->getEnvironment()
        ->getContextClassesWithArguments()['MyContext'][0];

    if (isset($my_settings['my_setting']) && $my_settings['my_setting'] == 'on') {
        //do something here
    }
}
```

It seems to match the documentation, but `my_setting` remains `off` instead of being updated to `on`.

If I try to use a key which is at the root level of `my_profile` like this:

```
my_profile:
   my_config:
     setting_setting: data
```

With this is the export command:

```
export BEHAT_PARAMS='{"my_config":{"my_setting":"on"}}'
```

Then I get this error:

> In ArrayNode.php line 311:
>
> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
>   Unrecognized option "my_settings" under "testwork"
>
> Exception trace:
>    Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ArrayNode->normalizeValue() at /sites/scorecards/vendor/symfony/config/Definition/BaseNode.php:368
>    Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\BaseNode->normalize() at /sites/scorecards/vendor/symfony/config/Definition/Processor.php:35
>    Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Processor->process() at /sites/scorecards/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/ServiceContainer/ContainerLoader.php:81
>    Behat\Testwork\ServiceContainer\ContainerLoader->processConfig() at /sites/scorecards/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/ServiceContainer/ContainerLoader.php:65
>    Behat\Testwork\ServiceContainer\ContainerLoader->load() at /sites/scorecards/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Cli/Application.php:185
>    Behat\Testwork\Cli\Application->createContainer() at /sites/scorecards/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Cli/Application.php:161
>    Behat\Testwork\Cli\Application->createCommand() at /sites/scorecards/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Cli/Application.php:122
>    Behat\Testwork\Cli\Application->doRun() at /sites/scorecards/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:148
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /sites/scorecards/vendor/behat/behat/bin/behat:34

.. how can I fix this?

Comment: Might be wrong but you are using the key `DomainContext` on you env variable and then looking for `MyContext` in your code, could it be that?

Comment: @gvf in short MyContext is DomainContext.  I've updated the question so that the ambiguity is removed.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to remove `my_setting` from your yaml file
because it super-cedes any environment variable

from the documentation link you provided

> in order to specify a parameter in an environment variable, the value must not exist in your behat.yml

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tried that and it is not present in `$my_settings` now